# rake db:seed creates rows, but not the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

So when I run rake db:seed with some ruby to create 23 rows in a table, it creates the 23 rows but doesn't use the data I bring in. Code looks like this -

```
control_words = ControlWord.create([
 {:text => 'herp', :status => 'positive'},
 {:text => 'foo', :status => 'positive'}
])
```

It's probably something stupid but I've tried making an array and looping through each, but it gives me the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make `text` and `status` fields as non-null. Then use `ControlWord.create!` (with `!`) and see if you get errors.

I have a feeling that you may be missing `attr_accessible :text, :status` in your model, and those fields are probably nullable, thus no data and no errors.

Comment: Nope. That didn't fix it either.